# How to make activity not to be covered by the RecentApps?

Tags: android

I am working on a lock screen app.
When the lock screen activity is running,long pressing HOME key or pressing RecentApps key will call out the RecentApps screen and the screen lock will be bypassed.Then how can I avoid such thing happening?
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers.There must be something unclear in my question.I want HOME long pressing or RecentApps key on navigation bar not to work while my activity is running.

Comment: put code in manifest to avoid visible in recent apps by  android:excludeFromRecents="true" inside activity tag

Comment: @RaviKant I think OP is asking to just have that when the recent apps are shown from the lockscreen, and not when the screen isn't locked. Can OP make this clearer for us?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I am not trying to make my activity not to show in the RecentApps.I'm trying to make long pressing HOME or RecentApps key not to work while my activity is running.

Comment: I doubt it is possible to implement in Android. A working phone must always allow to place calls, otherwise such phone would not accepted for selling as prohibiting rules

Answer (score 1):

Use [`excludeFromRecents`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude) for your activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.package.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**EDIT:**

To not to show the Recent app dialog while your app is running try this:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(!hasFocus) {
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.juliencavandoli.com/how-to-disable-recent-apps-dialog-on-long-press-home-button/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: As you noted yourself in comments above, this is not that the OP was asking about )) Edit: Ops, I mistaken your nickname with @MarchingHome, sorry

Comment: @Mixaz true. Edited after OP's clarification. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: I didn't know that it's possible to close system dialogs, voting up then

Comment: Closing the system dialog has some drawbacks. First of all, you are still able to slide the system bar down which then pops back which doesn't look nicely. Additionally, it won't work on some devices. We have tested it on some Samsung Galaxy tabs. Some do, some don't.

Comment: @Denis Loh My activity shows in fullscreen,so the status bar is hidden.

Comment: I've tried your approach,but it doesn't work.Thank you all the same. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this function and call it from you `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`:

```
private void setAsLockScreen() {
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Additionally you have to add:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to your Manifest to avoid showing the app there. It is actually not required but nice to have.

Note: if you want to use multiple activities, your default lock screen will be shown for a very short period of time when the activities change. I posted a solution for that here: [Android lock screen multiple activities (a.k.a basic kiosk mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973884/android-lock-screen-multiple-activities-a-k-a-basic-kiosk-mode)

**Edit:** some additional notes on this approach. If you don't implement any function to leave your app in this mode you're locked :). In this case, you have to uninstall the app remotely.

If you also add the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` to your Activity and set it to the default launcher, it will start automatically after booting and you won't be able to tap on Home or Back anymore. The Recent App can be cleared by swiping out the other apps. If there are no other apps, you can't switch to other apps :)

Comment: Really interesting, I didn't know it's possible. I'll keep eye on this post ))

Comment: We are using this for a kiosk mode application.

Comment: OK,I will try this approach later.Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: @Denis Loh It seems that it did not  work.Any permission or other code need to be added?Or is there any limitation on where to call setAsLockScreen?

Comment: You must call the function from `onCreate` before any other drawing function. It is also not possible to change the window type after the application has created its views. There are no special permissions to set the application as lock screen.

Comment: Does it suggest that my application should not have any other activity created before my lockscreen activity?

Comment: Yes, because the window is already created if you have other activities running before setting the window type. This does only apply to the type! The window flags can be altered later.

Comment: I am afraid my app cannot be turned into one activity as the way you give in the post "... multiple activities".Because I am trying to add a screen lock in AOSP launcher.Is it possible to rebuild the activity when the activity is going to onPause or onWindowFocusChanged?

Comment: Have you tried to bypass starting the "default" launcher with your own launcher activity with the lock screen capability and when you unlocked the device you start the default launcher? In this case you dont have to change the default launcher. Would this be an option?

Comment: Yes,I forbade HOME key in this way,but it did not work on RecentApps.At last I set a receiver to listen the lock screen's onPause and restart it.And this approach works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

I used an Activity to decide to go to Launcher or LockScreenActivity by the symbol set in LockScreenActivity.This approach works well on HOME key forbiding,but does not work at all on RecentApps.

Then I registered a receiver to receive the action sent by LockScreenActivity's onPause method.When the action is received,restart the LockScreenActivity.And this works well.

LockScreenActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    Intent i = new Intent("xx.xx.xx.lockscreen.pause");
    sendBroadcast(i);
    mCheckLockHandler.postDelayed(mCheckRunnable, 500);//Check again
}

private Runnable mCheckRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("xx.xx.xx.lockscreen.pause");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

};
```

The receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction() == "xx.xx.xx.lockscreen.pause") {
        if(SettingsProvider.getBoolean(context, "locked", false)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```